# How can I perform a DFU from an ESP32 to the nRF52840?

Tags: embedded, esp32, firmware, nordic

I have a nRF52840 and an ESP32 and I want to perform a DFU to nRF52840 from ESP32, supposing I have the signed binary file in the ESP32. I was already able to perform the DFU to nRF52840 using MCUboot, making nRF52840 enter recovery mode and using a mcumgr client on my laptop to run

`mcumgr -t 20 --conntype serial --connstring=COM6 image upload app_update.bin`

but I don't know how can I perform the DFU from the ESP32. I am using Zephyr v3.1.99-ncs1 in nRF52840 and ESP-SDK in ESP32.

Comment: What does DFU stand for?

Comment: @Aaron Device Firmware Update. In other words, OP wants to flash a new firmware on the nRF52840 using an ESP32 rather than a PC.